# How to port this Linq to VS 2005

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-2.0

I have following code in VS2008

```
If Linq.Enumerable.Contains(Of String)(selectedUsersRoles, RoleCheckBox.Text) Then
    RoleCheckBox.Checked = True
Else
    RoleCheckBox.Checked = False
End If
```

I need the above code in VS2005

What can i do instead of linq in above code? Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you give us some more context please, e.g. What type is selectedUsersRoles (i.e. what's the question mark here "Dim selectedUsersRoles as ?"), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RoleCheckBox.Checked = False
For Each str As String in selectedUsersRoles
     If str = RoleCheckBox.Text Then
          RoleCheckBox.Checked = True
          Exit For
     End If
Next
```

If you don't wish to alter the RoleCheckBox.Checked twice (when str is actually found) then declare a boolean flag (i.e. boolFound) with an initial False value, change it to true when found, and asign RoleCheckBox.Checked = boolFound after the "for each" loop....

Answer (score 1):

```
bool containsRole = false;
foreach(string entry in selectedUsersRoles)
{
  if(entry == RoleCheckBox.Text)
  {
    containsRole = true;
    break;
  }
}

RoleCheckBox.Checked = containsRole;
```

The code is C# but i guess u'll get the idea.
This is for IEnumerable. If you have a list try Binary Worrier's sollution.